# How to move migrations files to outside of django project?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-packages

1. 

- django-project/

  - migrations/

    - app1/
    - .../
  - src/

    - app1/
    - .../
    - config/

      - ...
      - settings.py

how to set the path in MIGRATION_MODULES in settings.py to make generated migration files appear in migrations/app1/ folder?

I have tried
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'app1': '..migrations.app1.db_migrations'}
but got errors.

2. Is not it a bad practice to move migration files from default location?

Answer (score 1):

To move the migration files outside of your Django project, you can do the following:

- Make a new directory outside of your Django project to store the
  migrations files. In your Django project's settings.py file, set the
  MIGRATION_MODULES setting to a dictionary that maps the app labels
  to the new directory that you created. For example:

> ```
> MIGRATION_MODULES = {
>     'app_name': 'path.to.migration.module',
> }
> ```

- Move the migrations files for each app to the new directory.
- Run the makemigrations and migrate management commands as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
However, I have already tried this and got an error:
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'app1': 'django-project.migrations.app1',
}

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-project'

Comment: your path to migration module seems wrong. 
change it to django-project.migrations

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.

In settings.py you are going to add these lines:

```
import os, sys

# Path to django-project/ from __file__ or settings.py
proj_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# Path to the migration folder
new_mig_folder = os.path.join(proj_dir, 'migrations/')

# And to add the folder to the path
sys.path.append(new_mig_folder) 
# Hurrah when you execute the code it will know to look for files in this folder

# Tell Django where the migration files are if not default location
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'app1': 'app1.folder', # If in subfolder
    'app2': 'app2_mig', # If files directly in migrations/app2_mig/
    'app3': 'whatever_you_want_to_call_it',
    }
```